# How can I export a HTML table to Excel with a grid

Tags: jquery, excel

I'm very new in exporting table/data to Excel or PDF. However so far I have written jQuery for exporting a HTML table to Excel (xls). The problem is that it does not show the grid of the excel. Here is the example of the output in Excel.

[image: Export Problems]

Here is my code to export:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnExport").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //getting data from our table
    var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
    var table_div = document.getElementById('table_id');
    var table_html = table_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');

    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = data_type + ', ' + table_html;
    a.download = 'exported_salmon_' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 9999999) + 1000000) + '.xls';
    a.click();
  });
});
```

Here is my HTML

```
<table  id="table_id" class="data-table">
<caption class="title">Sales Salmon Usage Per 1K</caption>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th><center>NO</center></th>
    <th><center>OUTLET</center></th>
    <th><center>DATE</center></th>
    <th><center>SALES</center></th>
    <th><center>USAGE</center></th>
    <th><center>USAGE PER 1K</center></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php



$storenum=$_POST['search'];
$store_name=$_POST['storename'];
$store_region=$_POST['region'];
$date1 = $_POST['date1'];
  $date11 = strtotime($date1);
  $date111 = date('Y-m',$date11);
  $date112 = date('d',$date11);
  //date2
  $date2 = $_POST['date2'];
  $date21 = strtotime($date2);
  $date211 = date('Y-m',$date21);
  $date2111= date('F Y',$date21);
  $date212 = date('d',$date21);
  $t = date('t',$date21);
  $x=(($date212-$date112)+1)/$t;



 //input date1 and date2
 if ((!empty($date1)) && (!empty($date2)) && (empty($storenum)) && 
(empty($store_region))){
    //my$query = "";

 }

//input storenum, date1,date2
else if ((!empty($storenum)) && (!empty($date1)) && (!empty($date2)) && 
(empty($store_region))){
   //my$query = "";
 }


//input region, date1,date2
else if ((!empty($store_region)) && (!empty($date1)) && (!empty($date2)) && 
(empty($storenum))){
  //my$query = "";


 } 


  // Execute the query, or else return the error message.
  $result = $dbhandle->query($query) or exit("Error code ({$dbhandle->errno}): {$dbhandle->error}");

$no   = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  //someofmycode...


   echo "<tr class='y_n';>"; 
   echo "<td><center>".$no."</center></td>"; 
   echo "<td>".$store_name."</td>"; 
   echo "<td>".$date2111."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$netamt11."</td>"; 
   echo "<td>".$usage11."</td>";  
   echo "<td>".$duh1."</td>";
   echo "</tr>"; 
  $no++;
   } ?>

</tbody>
<tfoot>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="5">TOTAL</th>
    <th><?=($total)?></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <th colspan="5">AVERAGE <?php echo $actionstatus2 ?></th>

  <?php   

   //someofmycodecondition...                                                               


  ?>
  <th><?php echo number_format($X,4)?></th></tr>
 <tr>
 <th colspan="6"><center><?php echo $actionstatus?></center></th>
 </tr>

</tfoot>

  </table>

</h4></center>


   <div class="box">
   <center><input id="btnExport" type="submit" class="button" value="  EXPORT  "></center>
   </div>
   </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            $objPHPExcel->createSheet();
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(6);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Test')->setCellValue('A1', 'Chapter')
                ->setCellValue('B1', 'Topic')
                ->setCellValue('C1', 'Test')
                ->setCellValue('D1', 'Total Questions')
                ->setCellValue('E1', 'Time');
            $o=2;
            foreach($test as $testval)
            {
                $connection = Yii::$app->db;
                $chapname2 = "SELECT name as 'chapter' from chapter  Where id = '".$testval['chapter_id']."' ORDER BY name ASC";
                $command = $connection->createCommand($chapname2);
                $value = $command->queryOne();

                $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(6)
                    ->setCellValue('A'.$o, $value['chapter'])
                    ->setCellValue('B'.$o, $testval['name'])
                    ->setCellValue('C'.$o, $testval['test'])
                    ->setCellValue('D'.$o, $testval['total_questions'])
                    ->setCellValue('E'.$o, $testval['test_time']);
                $topicID[] = $testval['id'];

                $o++;
            }
```